# NokiaX takes really long to get screenshot from android monitor tool

Tags: android, monitor, nokiax

Taking a screen shot on a NokiaX (**device**) via the monitor tool is really time consuming. It takes about 40seconds to a min. Other Androids take about 1-2 seconds.

Am I missing some setting here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I per say. Doesn't really use apps to make screen shots you can just hold down the power button and volume button(decrease volume) for a couple of and its done

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done any sort of tweaks and taking screenshots takes pretty much the same time it does on a reference device. Using emulator the time seems to vary quite a lot. It's around 5-10s on both Nokia X AVD and AOSP 4.1.2 AVD. Actual device is 1-2s.

Are you using the same environment when testing both devices?

Comment: I am using a device here.